# Saving file in specific drive

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am manipulating data into a matrix (`X`), I am using this code:

```
fid=fopen('Data','w+');
fprintf(fid,'%6.3f %6.3f\n,X);
fclose(fid);
```

to create a file named `'Data'`, I want to save that file in a specific drive on the network. I am looking for the matlab code to use in my script to save the file in that drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file you can provide its **full path** to matlab

```
fid = fopen( '//myDrive/myFolder/Data.txt', 'w' );
```

In full path you can also provide drive letter

```
% open 'd:\subFolder\data.txt'
fid = fopen( fullfile( 'd:', 'subFolder', 'data.txt'), 'w' );
```

You may find `fullfile` command useful as it helps you agnostic of the operating system you are using (decides for you to use '\' or '/')